# When my POST request has many items, I get a error "StatusCode: 502, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Gateway'"

Tags: xamarin, httpclient

I have an Order and Items class. When my Order object has many Items, I get the error. But when it has few Items it works normally.

[image]

My POST resquest:

```
        try
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(endPoint));
            if (data != null && data.Count > 0)
            {
                request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data),
                    Encoding.UTF8,
                    "application/json");

                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            }

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            if (headers != null)
            {
                foreach (var header in headers)
                {
                    request.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
                }
            }

            var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            App.HandleException(ex);
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Which language this code is? Certainly not C.

Comment: all 500 errors are server errors.  You need to talk to your server team, or debug the server yourself.

Comment: I'm putting "C #" but when saving the changes it inserts the "C"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that your POST is sending a very large amount of unnecessary data in JSON unintentionally. I had this problem when I was working with inheritance.

Debug on the line:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

Check if it is being sent is really what is needed.

Comment: True, I am using the Realm database and my classes are inheriting from RealmObject. I converted to ViewModel and it worked.